# linked server db2 sql server '@' appearing in query results

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server

I have setup a linked server from sql server to DB2. For some strange reason '@' is appearing in the result set from a query that performs where not exists between tables of sql server and db2.

The type of the field is varchar(27) not null.

Thanks

Comment: Does @ appear in the DB2 table? What if you don't use NOT EXISTS? I've used DB2 linked servers and never seen this

Comment: No it does not appear on the table records.  It only appears when I do a select from SqlServer where not exists in DB2 <condition>